# Is it possible to contract the plague by kissing a wild chipmunk?"

Tags: microbiology, health, infection, epidemiology, infectious-diseases

I watched  [this cute video](https://www.facebook.com/thedodosite/videos/1855786437889356/?__xts__[0]=68.ARBJ5bHH_xdxaKT9ImpGCfUPK31ynEyVciu2GehQa_4qWsyvZNHgWNe-VFIA2eSgSQZ4Bn8XeQuA4mvyl_75s85cXBGJEmb57ZqirX4lI9kIXOY_pliuHJWVg2O6Q_ULDlzRLjvpegiplZh7hy6wJsQilrGF0Fnd-FD6pp0WDmi_dEyA3jWea3HIRnKXp78hq1kaFIIDj8VmSBlUAJRS0Ynnajm-tXcJGuyB6JZTUJwhirfHQSFKvYEm5GCRPuKbr4lg4-bGZpINJvCraquB1sS3Y2bpwF1mut6-h7SLMCvjxkW4OF71zu-PkXiYa5xjwSind9BisoSr-rnQ6XOTlP-WxmzeGMyEcEm6xy-mUTegu-gQkMp6OuK5hgwbWV7MtcA&__tn__=-R) and I came to conclusion that the lady in the video is putting her life in danger. She kisses a wild chipmunk.

As I know, they have fleas, and fleas have a black plague. Am I right? But maybe the risk of infection in contact with just one chipmunk is low?

How dangerous is such behaviour?

Comment: Very dangerous. Cute videos rot the mind (of those that watch them).

Comment: I suggest replacing the question title with the one you're actually asking: "Is it possible to contract the plague by kissing a wild chipmunk?"

Comment: I was going to vote close for opinion-based, but apparently this is actually a risk: https://www.cdc.gov/plague/resources/PlagueEcologyUS.pdf

Comment: @Armatus Yes, transmission risks are generally well studied and not opinion based. If you get a VTC as opinion based itch, hold off for someone who has specific knowledge

Comment: @DeNovo "As I know" is a signal phrase for opinion basis, but as you can see I do double check

Comment: @Armatus a quick search is not always a good way to tell whether something is or isn't opinion based. Be wary of the opinion based VTC, which is often a "not my field" VTC.

Comment: @Armatus this was a great suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

The causative agent of the plague, *Yersinia pestis*, can be indirectly (via a flea vector) or directly (via exposure to infectious fluid or a bite) transmitted by rodents. In the western United States in particular, *Y. pestis* is endemic, and ground squirrels, prairie dogs, chipmunks, and woodrats are important reservoirs (see Cecil Medicine Ch. 320). US National parks have signs warning against feeding squirrels and chipmunks for this reason. You can read more about it in a [national park brochure](https://www.nps.gov/public_health/zed/plague/Plague_job.pdf) . Chipmunks and squirrels indirectly and directly transmit a variety of other diseases as well, including Tularemia (Cecil Ch 319) and various tick and flea borne encephalitides.

Comment: Can you also tell how dangerous is it for that lady? I mean except for kissing the chipmunk, she doesn't seem to be a poor medieval peasant. Not even a poor modern day folk. Maybe if she is generally clean, such cute act poses a low risk? And if she contracts plague, how doomed is she? I wonder how much darkness lurks in this cute video.

Comment: @user46147 *Y. pestis* infection is treatable, though it can cause loss of limb or death, especially if diagnosis is delayed. It's not a common disease. There are a few thousand cases globally every year. Exposure to the chipmunk is a risk factor, regardless of whether she is a medieval peasant or royalty, and it is a risk factor for more than just the plague.